# How to edit source while debugging Electron App

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, electron, atom-editor

It would be very convenient if I could edit my JavaScript source code while debugging my electron-react application. I notice I seem to almost edit:

[image: Me able to edit - no save yet]

However when I actually try to save this `render.js` file I get this error:

[image: Error when trying to save]

How do I allow for the JavaScript file to be edited? I don't mind reloading the application after I editing it. For now, I edit on my Atom IDE then allow `gulp` to recompile for me. I suppose I could also edit my `render.js` file in Atom, but that file is huge and not friendly.